# Overriding URLField's validation with custom validation

Tags: python, regex, django

How can I override django's URLField's validation with a custom validation? And where should this be done?

I want it to accept urls without a domain ending too.

Comment: Form Field oder Model Field?

Answer (score 7):

This is Django's [Url Field Validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#urlvalidator). Provide your custom regular expression myregex to it. However, you need to prevent the UrlField default validation, since this is not want you want.

So create your custom field like that:
Then for your model / form, provide this to the field like that:

```
from django.forms import UrlField as DefaultUrlField
class UrlField(DefaultUrlField):
    default_validators = [URLValidator(regex=myregex)]
```

And then in your Form just do:

```
my_url_field = UrlField()
```

Comment: This seemed to add the validation "on top" of the URLField's default validation

Comment: It's URLField not UrlField.

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom regex validation or can use Django URL Validation on your models:

Option1:

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
URL_VALIDATOR_MESSAGE = 'Not a valid URL.'
URL_VALIDATOR = RegexValidator(regex='/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/', message=URL_VALIDATOR_MESSAGE)


class SocialAccounts(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("Profile", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    facebook = models.URLField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, validators=[URL_VALIDATOR])
```

Option2:

```
from django.core.validators import URLValidator
class OptionalSchemeURLValidator(URLValidator):
    def __call__(self, value):
        if '://' not in value:
            # Validate as if it were http://
            value = 'http://' + value
        super(OptionalSchemeURLValidator, self).__call__(value)


class SocialAccounts(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("Profile", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    facebook = models.URLField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, validators=[OptionalSchemeURLValidator])
    instagram = models.URLField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True,
                                validators=
                                    [RegexValidator(
                                        regex= '/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/',
                                        message='Not a valid URL',
                                    )])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about use a CharField (superclass of URLField) with your own validator,

See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54371681/7728887) if it can help. thx!